# Bind Android Service to libgdx core module

Tags: android, libgdx, android-service

I'm searching for a way to bind a Android Service from my Game Class.

My Application tree looks like:

1. DW

   - android

     - src

       - com.dw.game.android

         - DWService
   - core

     - src

       - com.dw.game

         - DWGame

Has libgdx some methods for that? Is there another way to use Android Service with libgdx?